# How to generate a Java Class from a database for use with Hibernate 4

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, orm, code-generation

I want to use Hibernate 4 to work with the database. I use this configuration to map tables in database with Java class:

```
<mapping class="test.table1"></mapping>
```

In my Java class I define compatible fields with the table. But now I want to generate the compatible fields automatically. Is there any tool to do it?

I'm using Java 1.7 and MySQL.

Comment: Fixed the code formatting (4 space) and cleaned up the grammar. However, you probably need to provide more detail about your environment (which database are you using?) and explain a bit more what you are trying to accomplish. If you've tried something already, what was insufficient or broken?

Comment: I'm using java 1.7 and MySQL

Comment: Tidy up grammar and add the MySQL tag as it might be important.  However, we still need to see more of your code to help you with your situation.

Comment: Do you want generate a Java class from a Db table, or the inverse, generate a Db table from a Java class entity?

Comment: I want to generate java Class form Data Base

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to generate some Java classes based on the schema defined in your database why don’t you use a **code generator** designed for this kind of job?

For example you could use **Telosys**, it’s a very handy tool that can create a “database model” in a few minutes by connecting to an relational DB and then use it to generate any kind of code and especially Java classes.

The advantage is that you can adapt the templates if necessary (and if you want you can generate more than the domain classes).

For more information see the web site http://www.telosys.org/ and read this article https://modeling-languages.com/telosys-tools-the-concept-of-lightweight-model-for-code-generation/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Hibernate Tools Reverse Engineer](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/4.0.1.Final/en/hibernatetools/html/plugins.html#refeng_codegen), which inspects the database and generates the domain model classes from the database table definition.